# Ubuntu on a live usb

Tags: boot, usb, live-usb

I want to  try ubuntu for first time , I am a total noob and not used any Linux distros before what I want to ask is I want to create a bootable live usb with ubuntu but i am creating it on a usb 2.0 so will it be very slow, I also want to add persistence to it and also can it delete or affect any data on my main hardrive when using ubuntu on my persistent live usb as i am a noob and don't want to destroy my windows and other files.

Answer (score 0):

I ran not only live USB but also complete installed Ubuntu from USB 2.0. It woks fine for most of the time.

making a live USB do not make any change to your present system. because you just write a ISO image on a USB using software like Unetbootin. During booting you have to select boot from USB option.

If you want a persistent system you have to install complete Ubuntu on a USB or Hard disk. Live USB do not save changes.

The installation of Ubuntu or any other OS only erase/ destroy data from your existing OS Hard Disk if you select to overwrite that disk. If you take care and install Ubuntu properly on another disk/ partition your existing OS shall be intact.

In some cases of dual Boot like Ubuntu and Windows some may face Boot problem. That can be repaired using Boot-Repair from Live USB.

Answer (score 0):

Using Unetbootin there is an option to add persistance to your USB drive .Works for Ubuntu and its derivatives.Just download the ISO from Ubuntu and point Unetbootin to it.and follow prompts. Google unetbootin to find version for your windows machine.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to make a dual boot installation too. Ubuntu 20.04 makes it very simple. Also if you have a windows machine i would suggest Rufus as your best alternative to create a bootable usb. It allows you to create persistent live usb's.

Comment: Rufus does not need to be installed in Windows, just double clicking the .exe file will launch it.

Answer (score 0):

Glad to hear that you've decided to switch to Ubuntu.

To answer your first question, using USB 2.0 to create a live USB **will not significantly impact speeds**. You should be able to use the USB with no problems at all.

You can create a live USB with persistence by following [this tutorial.](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/14912/create-a-persistent-bootable-ubuntu-usb-flash-drive/)

Your live USB session is exclusive from your Windows installation, and unless you're reformatting or re-partitioning disks your **Windows installation is safe.**

Welcome to the community, and I hope this helped!

Answer (score 0):

### Ubuntu Install Quick Start

Download Ubuntu 20.04 https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop

Start with a USB of at least 4GB formatted FAT32.

If using Windows, download Rufus. https://rufus.ie/

Double click the Rufus .exe file. (No need to install).

[image: ![enter image description here]

Select USB Device and Ubuntu ISO file for Boot Selection.

Stretch the Persistent partition size almost to the end.

Select `START`

When Rufus is done you can use USB to install Ubuntu to BIOS or UEFI machine.