# Can you make a Live USB with the persistent partition in my main, internal Hard Drive instead of in Live usb itself?

Tags: partitioning, usb, live-usb

I want to Try out a few versions of Linux in some Live USB's, and Don't know a way to make the persistent partition in the main computer/HDD(in a different partition, of course) instead of in the live USB itself. But, is it possible? if so, How? (I use a windows 10) trying to use my work PC with windows as a Linux with live USB with persistent partition:)

thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Make a Live USB with the persistent partition in main, internal Hard Drive.

- A Persistent USB will use the first Persistent partition it sees. Usually a persistent partition on the internal HDD is first.
- The Persistent partition needs to be an ext partition, say ext4.
- The partition should be labelled `casper-rw`, (Labelling it `writable` is optional for 20.04).
- A second Persistent partition labelled `home-rw` can be used for home data and settings.
- The `casper-rw` partition will not work with another version of 'Buntu, a `home-rw` partition will.
- The word `persistent` should also be added to the `linux` line in grub.cfg:

  `linux ($root)/casper/vmlinuz boot=casper quiet splash fsck.mode=skip persistent --`
- You can also choose to boot multiple ISO files, each with it's own persistence files. For reference see:

[20.04 booting .iso from GRUB menu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1251729/20-04-booting-iso-from-grub-menu/1251782#1251782)

In your case the grub boot loader can be on external USB drive. A mkusb persistent drive uses GRUB 2, the menu can be modified to work.

**Warning:**

Booting a different Persistent USB in the computer will try to use the Persistent partition. If it contains a different version of Ubuntu It may corrupt the casper-rw partition, (but not a home-rw partition).

Comment: thank you, Casper! I'm sorry, but I am a complete noob in Linux. So just to clarify, I should:  1:make an ext4 partition I'm my HDD named:casper-rw, and, 2:when I boot my live USB, in the terminal, run:  linux ($Root)/casper/MyPcName boot=casper quiet splash fsck.mode=skip persistent --



??? Is that right? again, sorry for my lack of knowledge!
one more thing, what is:grub.cf???? sorry, I have no idea!
thanks again, for your help!

Comment: What tool did you use to make your Live USB? The method is a little different for each one. Rufus is probably easiest. see https://askubuntu.com/questions/1257741/ubuntu-on-a-live-usb/1257876#1257876. After creating the casper-rw partition on your HDD, Rufus will use it when the USB is booted on that computer. It will use the Persistent partition on the USB when booted on a different computer. You can make the persistent partition on the USB a NTFS data partition if you like. The persistent partition on the USB will be named "casper-rw" or "writable" depending on the version of Ubuntu.

Comment: Thank you soo much C.S.Cameron! it worked! thank you for your time, and help! cheers!

Comment: @code geek: I have added info on home-rw partitions and a warning about booting USBs with different versions of 'Buntu.

Comment: thank you very much C.S.Cameron! as always, very helpful!!!